# Is there any way to run an application as a screensaver in Linux

Tags: linux, screensaver

I want to run a full-screen application as a screen saver. Is it possible in Linux?
It seems that [XScreenSaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) is not capable of doing this and [GnomeScreenSaver](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/) has this in their wish list.

Comment: any specific applications? is the application under your control?

Comment: It would be great to run any full-screen application as a screen saver. But if it's not possible (why?) I'm ok with modifying my app.

Comment: I'm just looking for easy way for implementing Linux screen savers.

Comment: For a program to work as a screensaver, for xscreensaver, it just needs to be able to draw on the X11 root window.  All the graphics hacks that come with xscreensaver have a -root option for this reason.  If you run /usr/lib/xscreensaver/moebius, it will just draw in a window.  They all have --help options.

Answer (score 3):

An (untested) trick that might work would be to run your program under [Xnest](http://www.xfree86.org/4.3.0/Xnest.1.html).

something like this pseudo shellcode may work:

```
#get root window id
RWINID=$(xwininfo -root |sed -n -e 's/.*Window.*id: \(0x[a-f0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')
#start Xnest on the root window
Xnest -parent $RWINID :5
DISPLAY=":5" myapp
```

Comment: That's so crazy it might just work to screen-saverize an arbitrary program. :P  BTW, Xephyr is the recommended successor to XNest.  It support the RENDER extension...